implementation of concurrent map in C++(17)
I want to implement concurrent map in C++ with the following requirements:
static_assert at the beginning of the class indicates that in this task it is assumed that only integer numbers can be keys of ConcurrentMap.
The constructor of the class ConcurrentMap<K, V> takes the number of sub-dictionaries into which the entire key space should be divided.
operator[] should behave the same way as the analogous operator in map - if the key key is present in the dictionary, it should return an object of the Access class containing a reference to its corresponding value; if key is absent in the dictionary, a pair (key, V()) should be added to it, and an object of the Access class containing a reference to the newly added value should be returned.
The structure Access should behave the same way as in the Synchronized template - providing a reference to the dictionary value and ensuring synchronization of access to it.
The BuildOrdinaryMap method should merge together parts of the dictionary and return the entire dictionary as a whole. At the same time, it should be thread-safe, i.e., work correctly when other threads perform operations on ConcurrentMap.
My implementation:
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


template <typename K, typename V>
class ConcurrentMap {
public:
    static_assert(is_integral_v<K>, "ConcurrentMap supports only integer keys");

    struct Access {
        Access(V&  value, mutex& m) : ref_to_value(value), guard(m){};
        V& ref_to_value;
        lock_guard<mutex> guard;
    };

    explicit ConcurrentMap(size_t bucket_count) : current_thread(bucket_count - 1), bucket_count(bucket_count),conc_map(bucket_count) {};

    Access operator[](const K& key){
        if(keys_threads.count(key) > 0){
            size_t thread_num = keys_threads[key];
            return {conc_map[thread_num].second.at(key),conc_map[thread_num].first};
        } else{
            current_thread = (current_thread == bucket_count - 1) ? 0 : current_thread + 1;
            conc_map[current_thread].second[key] = V();
            keys_threads[key] = current_thread;
            return {conc_map[current_thread].second.at(key),conc_map[current_thread].first};
        }
    };

    map<K, V> BuildOrdinaryMap(){
        lock_guard<mutex> guard_map(ordinary_map_mutex);
        map<K,V> ordinary_map;
        for(auto& thread_map:conc_map){
            ordinary_map.insert(thread_map.second.begin(),thread_map.second.end());
        }
        return ordinary_map;

    };
private:
    vector<pair<mutex,map<K,V>>> conc_map;
    map<K,size_t> keys_threads;
    size_t current_thread;
    size_t bucket_count;
    mutex ordinary_map_mutex;
    };

My ide: I will create a vector of the size of the number of buckets/threads; each element of the vector is a pair of mutex and map, where each mutex will protect corresponding map.
Additional explanation to the operator[]

if key is present (checked by .count method in keys_threads map), then I retrieve a  bucket (number) in which key was saved (size_t thread_num = keys_threads[key];) and then return an Access object, which will give an access to the value of the map under mutex ( {conc_map[thread_num].second.at(key),conc_map[thread_num].first};)
if key is absent: I calculate a bucket/thread, where new element will be saved (if current_thread is equal to the bucket_count - 1, then I reset it to 0, else I increase it by 1), then I add empty element to the bucket (conc_map[current_thread].second[key] = V();), then I add key, thread pair to the keys_threads map and return an Access object, which will give an access to the new value of the map under mutex ({conc_map[current_thread].second.at(key),conc_map[current_thread].first};)

I run couple of tests, but unfortunately mutex doesn't protect against simultaneous changes. Can you please give me a hint, where I made mistake/mistakes (I can assume it has to do with thread calculation, but I am not sure).
Tests:
void RunConcurrentUpdates(
    ConcurrentMap<int, int>& cm, size_t thread_count, int key_count
) {
    auto kernel = [&cm, key_count](int seed) {
    vector<int> updates(key_count);
    iota(begin(updates), end(updates), -key_count / 2);
    shuffle(begin(updates), end(updates), default_random_engine(seed));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (auto key : updates) {
            cm[key].ref_to_value++;
        }
    }
};

    vector<future<void>> futures;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) {
        futures.push_back(async(kernel, i));
    }
}

void TestConcurrentUpdate() {
    const size_t thread_count = 3;
    const size_t key_count = 50000;

    ConcurrentMap<int, int> cm(thread_count);
    RunConcurrentUpdates(cm, thread_count, key_count);

    const auto result = cm.BuildOrdinaryMap();
    ASSERT_EQUAL(result.size(), key_count);
    for (auto& [k, v] : result) {
        AssertEqual(v, 6, "Key = " + to_string(k));
    }
    }

void TestReadAndWrite() {
    ConcurrentMap<size_t, string> cm(5);

    auto updater = [&cm] {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
        cm[i].ref_to_value += 'a';
    }
    };
    auto reader = [&cm] {
    vector<string> result(50000);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        result[i] = cm[i].ref_to_value;
    }
    return result;
    };

    auto u1 = async(updater);
    auto r1 = async(reader);
    auto u2 = async(updater);
    auto r2 = async(reader);

    u1.get();
    u2.get();

    for (auto f : {&r1, &r2}) {
    auto result = f->get();
    ASSERT(all_of(result.begin(), result.end(), [](const string& s) {
        return s.empty() || s == "a" || s == "aa";
    }));
    }
}

where AssertEqual and ASSERT_EQUAL are custom classes/functions.

For requirements on types do not use static_assert your functions will still be considered by the compiler. Use concepts or SFINAE to reduce the allowed types. The easiest way to make a map threadsafe is to wrap std::map (do NOT inherit from std::map) and make small acces functions that lock a mutes (using std::scoped lock). No need to implement the map logic all over again yourself. Added bonus you can stick to std::map's default methods on your api as well. (though probably I would just add a std::scoped_lock to my current code and just call std::map directly)

In operator[], access to keys_threads is not protected by a mutex, you can't call operator[] from multiple threads.

@PepijnKramer static_assert and SFINAE serve different purposes. If you need a static assertion, use static_assert, if you need SFINAE, use SFINAE. Don't use SNIFAE when you need a static assertion.

@Evg there is a big difference between the two, static assert will give "nicer" error message. But if you don't sfinae out a function you may prevent other functions from matching. Because the one with the static assert was a better match initially. So use static_assert with care. (Since I work in huge code bases I usually have to take the long view and not always pick the initially more easy solution)
